# Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.x! Detected version: 17.0.1 in Windows 10

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, java-17

I am trying to build an apk for Android. when I run the command `ionic cordova build android` I get the error:
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting) ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED) Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.x! Detected version: 17.0.1 Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.

App · Command "cordova" failed with exit code: 1 App · Updated Cordova config.xml App · ⚠️ [FAIL] Cordova CLI has failed

It says I need JDK 1.8.x, but it detected  But I am pretty sure I have JDK 1.8 installed

my JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1`

I have no idea why I can't get the app to build. Please help!

Comment: apart of setting properly variables you should
1. close and open terminal to reflect changes
2. delete windows cache as this can ben sometimes cached and brings headache when trying to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your JAVA_HOME entry and put there path to JDK 1.8 installation.

Comment: How can I Do that?As I know Setting the environment path of JAVA_HOME means setting the JDK path only And in JAVA_HOME I have already set my JDK path.Still error is coming

Comment: Just try to use JDK 1.8 and not JDK 17. So download it first and then set JAVA_HOME accordingly.